# Математические операции над значением ng-model в AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеется следующая задача - вывести массив данных при помощи AngularJS. Часть данных представлена в численной форме и помещается в input.

Соответственно, значение в этом input может быть отредактировано и передано обратно к API.

В коде input выглядит так:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="product.price">
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы имеющееся значение ng-model как при инициализации, так и при изменении данных было равно не тому, которое возвращается по API, а, например, разделено на 10.

Есть ли возможность такое реализовать?

Перечитал множество мануалов и похожих вопросов, но решения так и не нашел. Заранее спасибо!

**UPDATE**
Не совсем удачно выразился в вопросе: 
Суть в том, что я хочу, чтобы конструкция подобного вида

```
<input type="number" ng-model="product.price / 10">
```

работала. То есть, не только отображала данные, как происходит сейчас, а также позволяла и отправлять эти данные.

**UPDATE 2**
Задача также осложняется тем, что массив данных я вывожу при помощи ng-repeat. То есть, конечная конструкция такая:

```html
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td><input type="number" ng-model="product.price"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE 3**
Также добавлю пример кода контроллера:

```js
directApp.controller('campaignController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'url_to_get_data_from'
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: после получения по api - пробегитесь по всем данным и поменяйте которые нужно

Comment: Не очень понял Ваш ответ, но понял, что не совсем корректно сформулировал вопрос. Обновил информацию.

Comment: вы получаете в каком-то месте данные и заполняете `product.price` почему бы в месте заполнения вместо `product.price = value` сделать `product.price = value / 10`?

Comment: вообще не важно как выводите: покажите как заполняете

Comment: Снова моя вина - не написал, что вывожу данные при помощи ng-repeat. Таким образом не вижу возможности отобразить product.price,измененный внутри контроллера.

Comment: `$scope.products = data.map(function(el){ el.price = el.price/10; return el;});`

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Comment: @Grundy, оформите, пожалуйста, Ваш комментарий в ответ, я отмечу его как лучший. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если перед выводом полученных данных им нужна дополнительная обработка, ее лучше всего делать прямо в месте получения один раз.
В данном случае достаточно при получении данных пройтись по ним и изменить соответствующее поле, например так:

```
directApp.controller('campaignController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'url_to_get_data_from'
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data.map(function(el){ 
            el.price = el.price/10; //изменяем значение нужного поля
            return el;
        });
    });
});
```